# Detecting if SQL Server 2008 is installed

Tags: sql-server-2008, installation, bootstrapping, bootstrapper

I am using [dotNetInstaller](http://dotnetinstaller.codeplex.com/) as a bootstrapper and I need to detect if SQL Server 2008 or above is installed as a prerequisite.

Currently I am using this registry to detect the installation:
`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Redist\SharedManagementObjects\1033\CurrentVersion\Version`

If the value of `Version` is 10.0.0 or higher it detects it as installed.  We tried the installation package on 10 machines here (Windows XP SP3 & Windows 7) and the prerequisite worked fine. We are getting reports from a lot of people that although they have SQL 2008 installed it does not detect the install.

From the log:

```
2010-07-13 09:33:49 Checking whether registry value 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Redist\SharedManagementObjects\1033\CurrentVersion\Version' exists
2010-07-13 09:33:49 Opening 64-bit registry view (KEY_WOW64_64KEY)
2010-07-13 09:33:49 *** No registry key found: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Redist\SharedManagementObjects\1033\CurrentVersion\Version, default value: false
2010-07-13 09:33:49 -- Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 x86 (Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 x86 Express): NOT INSTALLED
```

dotNetInstaller Check:

```
<installedcheck type="check_registry_value"
                                            rootkey="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE"
                                            path="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Redist\SharedManagementObjects\1033\CurrentVersion"
                                            fieldname="Version"
                                            fieldtype="REG_SZ"
                                            fieldvalue="10.0.0"
                                            comparison="version_ge"
                                            wowoption="WOW64_64"
                                            defaultvalue="False"
                                            description="Installed Check" />
```

Does anyone know the definitive key to check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the key I was using only detects if the tools are installed.  I'm going to use this key: `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Bootstrap Release\1033\CurrentVersion\Version`

Answer (score 2):

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Bootstrap\Setup

PatchLevel
```

Appears to be a more likely candidate as it's updated by both the R2 and R2 SP1 installations.

Answer (score 1):

They're not using [SQL Server 2008 Developer Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/developer.aspx) are they?  I think the key might be different at the "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Redist" level, but I don't have it here to check.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 Express for all