# How to verify successful installation of SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: powershell, sql-server-2008-r2, verification

I'm trying to install SQL Server 2008 R2 silently using a PowerShell script.
After the installation I need to verify that the installation is successful.
Is there any way to check something like exit code in `sqlsetup.log` file for successful installation?

Following is the code, I'm currently using:-

```
# Read current directory
$ScriptPath = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$ParentDir = Split-Path $scriptpath

#Read Config file from current directory
$ConfigFile = $ParentDir + '\ConfigurationFile.ini'
Write-Host $ConfigFile
#Holds base setup from current directory
$SetupFile=$ParentDir + '\setup.exe'
Write-Host $SetupFile
$SP3SetupFile=$ParentDir + '\SQLServer2008R2_SP3\Setup.exe'
Write-Host $SP3SetupFile

#Start of the log file
$Start="========================================================================================"
$Start | Out-File $env:temp\InstallSQL2008R2_log.txt -append

#Printsd the current date and time in log file
$Date=Get-Date
$Date | Out-File $env:temp\InstallSQL2008R2_log.txt -append

#Starting with the SQL base installation
$InstallBaseSQL="Installing SQL Server 2008 R2"
$InstallBaseSQL | Out-File $env:temp\InstallSQL2008R2_log.txt -append

#Installs SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard Edition 
& "$SetupFile" /ConfigurationFile="$ConfigFile"

#Checks whether properly installed 
$ExistString = Select-String -Path "$env:temp\SqlSetup*.log" -Pattern "Setup closed with exit code: 0x00000000"
if($ExistString)  
    {  
        $SuccessStatus = "Installation of SQL Server 2008 R2 completed"
        $SuccessStatus | Out-File $env:temp\InstallSQL2008R2_log.txt -append
        #write-host "Installation of SQL Server 2008 R2 completed"
        #out-file $env:temp\InstallSQL2008R2_log.txt -append   
       # $log.name | out-file $C:\FileContainingString.txt -append  
    }  
    else  
    {  
        $failStatus = "Installation couldn't complete, for more details please check sqlsetup.txt in temp folder"
        $FailStatus | Out-File $env:temp\InstallSQL2008R2_log.txt -append 
    }

#Installing sql patch
$InstallSQLSP3="Installing SQL Server 2008 R2 SP3"
$InstallSQLSP3 | Out-File $env:temp\InstallSQL2008R2_log.txt -append

#Install SQL Server 2008 R2 SP3 Patch
& "$SP3SetupFile" /instancename=MSSQLSERVER /quiet

#Completion Message
$PatchComplete="Installation of SQL Server 2008 R2 SP3 completed3"
$PatchComplete | Out-File $env:temp\InstallSQL2008R2_log.txt -append


$End="========================================================================================"
$End | Out-File $env:temp\InstallSQL2008R2_log.txt -append
```

Comment: Can't say I've ever seen anyone save every output to a new variable, then save it to a file. Why not pipe the string directly to `Out-File`? Anyway rather than check the log file you could check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257328/detecting-if-sql-server-2008-is-installed?rq=1) for a registry flag, but error code `0x00000000` (2nd last line of log) means no errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((Get-Content "$env:temp\SqlSetup*.log" -Encoding Unicode)[-2] -like "*0x00000000")
{
    ## Successfully installed
}
```

Checking the log for errors may not be 100%, you may also want to check `HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Bootstrap Release\1033\CurrentVersion\Version` or something too.